# Dynamic Application Security Testing (DAST) Scanner for Post Authentication

Tags: runtime, dynamic-analysis

I am wondering if anyone know's of a DAST Scanner than can either take in an `authenticated` request from somewhere like burp, OR some DAST software that takes `username` and `password`  and then run DAST scans against the target.

I've used a ton of DAST tools like `nessus`, `openvas`, etc but they all take in a target UNAUTHENTICATED, not AUTHENTICATED and then run DAST scans against the target.

Instead of saying go hit ip `1.2.3.4` i want to say, go to `1.2.3.4/user/account` for example.

Anyone have any programs that can run DAST as an authenticated user? e.g. run sqli, xss, dir traversal, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with that **Nessus and Openvas are not DAST tools**.

Burp is a very good option, you might go with, OWASP ZAP is similar, but it is 100% free.
Than there are other vendors like Rapid7 Insight AppSec (not InsightVM/Nexpose), Tenable Web Application Security (not Nessus), Synopsis, etc., a simple search on Google will give you a bunch of results with vendors.

All of the major vendors can hold a session active whilst doing the scan, that's one of the basics. I would suggest looking at the report quality, ability to integrate and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many modern active scanners support this functionality, such as Burp: https://support.portswigger.net/customer/en/portal/articles/2363088-configuring-burp-s-session-handling-rules

Burp allows you to configure session handling that lets the scanner know when a session has been invalidated, then run a macro to create a new valid session. This generally takes the form of a certain HTTP response that indicates a session is no longer valid, and a macro that fires an HTTP POST login request that sets a session cookie.